# Push Notifications with data on push Event

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, chrome-gcm

I am trying to push notifications using GCM,able to show notifications with hard coded data or message on Push Event.But when I tried to push custom messages using data object as Json,Push event is triggering but ,data object always shoeing as null.

**Service worker code:sw.js**

```
 self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
 console.log('Received a push message', event);
 console.log("event data",event.data);//here data is giving as null
var data=event.data.json();
var title= data.title||'No tiltle';
 var body= data.message||'no messgae';

event.waitUntil(
self.registration.showNotification(title, {
  body: body,
  icon: icon,
  tag: tag


  })
  );
  });
```

am using third party site(requestmaker.com) to check the notifications.
format am sending like below

```
 URL:https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
 content-type:application/json
 authorization:key=XXXXXXXXXX
```

below is data  format

```
 {
 "registration_ids":["someid"],
    "data":{"title":"hai",
    "body":"hello new message"
   }
 }
```

How can i get data in Push Event and in which format i have to send data as request sothat i can get that data on push event(event.data).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data on notification click trigger event.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {

 // here data you access from event using event.notification.data
  console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);

}
```

Comment: Want to show notifications on push event with that data as a message. 'notificationclick' event happens only after the notification popup comes and when we click on it rite.

Comment: check  if notification is granted or not using (!(self.Notification && self.notification.permission === 'granted')) {
    return;
  }

Answer (score 1):

From the push notification triggered, the payload data wont be sent across to the service worker. You will have to use browser auth keys while triggering the push notification for the payload to be sent across.

Please refer the documentation below for details.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption?hl=en

Comment: @Nitya: actually followed that link ,Encrypted the message then am getting 200 ok response but now the Push event is not triggering.

Comment: @venugopal: I had tried https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push library for sending with and without payload to firefox and chrome. May be try this library for sending with payload. 

Try the below link for usage details. Its really helpful with decent documentation and demo.
https://serviceworke.rs/push-get-payload_server_doc.html

Comment: Am using web push java library(https://github.com/MartijnDwars/web-push/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/martijndwars/webpush/PushService.java).So it is giving 200 Ok response but no event triggered.

Comment: var rawKey = pushSubscription.getKey ?                                 pushSubscription.getKey('p256dh') : '';
  console.log('rawkwy',rawKey);
  var key = rawKey ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(rawKey))) : '';
var rawAuthSecret = pushSubscription.getKey ? pushSubscription.getKey('auth') : '';
 var authSecret = rawAuthSecret ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  new Uint8Array(rawAuthSecret))) :

Comment: var content = {
 "registration_ids" : subId,
 "endpoint" :endpoint,
 "authKey":authKey,
 "PublicKey256":userkey256,
 "data.title":"hello"
 };
 $.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "/callGCM",
  dataType : "json",
  data : content,
     success : function(data) {
   alert("success");
    },
    error : function(e) 
    {
     alert("error"+e);
    }

Comment: @Server side:  in PushService.java from  above mentioned git link file

Comment: In send() method:        
            headers.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
            headers.put("Authorization",  gcmApiKey);
         
       
        List nameValuePair = new ArrayList();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_id",  regIds));       
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
      //  httpPost.setHeader("registration_id",  regIds);    
            return httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    }'